# Map the multiple columns from pandas dataframe and perform operations on it

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes namely df, and df1. I am interested in currency conversion for dataframe df.
In df dataframe we have 6 columns. First Column is Date and rest are currency values for respective dates. I want to convert these currencies into proper format. In dataframe df1 I have 2 columns, first is currency and second is operator.

I am interested in applying the respective operator on currency values from df.
for e.g in df we have second column namely "AUD" and i want to convert all 'AUD' values to proper format 
means multiply or divide by the respective "operator" column from dataframe df1.
Here 'AUD' have 'multiply' operator so all the values get multiplied by 1. and for 'CAD' is should be divided means 1/'CAD' values from 'CAD' columns.

```
import pandas as pd    
data = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019','01-01-2019'],
        'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97],
        'BWP':[30,31,33,32,31],
        'CAD':[50,52,51,51,52],
        'BND':[1.01,1.05,1.03,1.02,1.03],
        'COP':[20,21,23,21,22]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data1 = {'currency':['DZD', 'AUD', 'CNY', 'BND','BRL','BWP','CAD','COP'],
        'operator':['divide', 'multiply', 'divide', 'divide','divide','multiply','divide','divide'],
        }    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

```
df

         Date   AUD  BWP  CAD   BND  COP
0  01-01-2019  98.0   30   50  1.01   20
1  02-01-2019  98.5   31   52  1.05   21
2  03-01-2019  99.0   33   51  1.03   23
3  04-01-2019  99.5   32   51  1.02   21
4  05-01-2019  97.0   31   52  1.03   22
```

df1

```
  currency code  operator
0           DZD    divide
1           AUD  multiply
2           CNY    divide
3           BND    divide
4           BRL    divide
5           BWP  multiply
6           CAD    divide
7           COP    divide
```

Expected Output:

```
         Date   AUD  BWP     CAD    BND     COP
0  01-01-2019  98.0   30  0.0200  0.990   0.050
1  02-01-2019  98.5   31  0.0192  0.952   0.047
2  03-01-2019  99.0   33  0.0196  0.970   0.043
3  04-01-2019  99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  20.047
4  05-01-2019  97.0   31  0.0192  0.970   0.045
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
n=1
#Date set like index because you should not perform operations on this column
df=df.set_index('Date')
#Selecting columns where divide is necessary
div_code=df1.loc[df1['operator']=='divide','code']

#Creating a boolean indexing of columns
col_mask=df.columns.isin(div_code)

#Applying operations to data frame columns
df[df.columns[col_mask]]=n/df[df.columns[col_mask]]
df[df.columns[~col_mask]]=n*df[df.columns[~col_mask]]

#putting Date as a column again
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
         Date   AUD  BWP       CAD       BND       COP
0  01-01-2019  98.0   30  0.020000  0.990099  0.050000
1  02-01-2019  98.5   31  0.019231  0.952381  0.047619
2  03-01-2019  99.0   33  0.019608  0.970874  0.043478
3  04-01-2019  99.5   32  0.019608  0.980392  0.047619
4  05-01-2019  97.0   31  0.019231  0.970874  0.045455
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you store the data in `df1` as a dictionary:

```
operators = df1.set_index('currency')['operator'].to_dict()
df.apply(lambda col: col if operators.get(col.name, 'multiply') == 'multiply' else 1 / col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code that produces your expected output,

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
data = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '01-01-2019','01-01-2019'],
    'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97],
    'BWP':[30,31,33,32,31],
    'CAD':[50.00,52.00,51.00,51.00,52.00],
    'BND':[1.01,1.05,1.03,1.02,1.03],
    'COP':[20.00,21.00,23.00,21.00,22.00]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data1 = {'currency':['DZD', 'AUD', 'CNY', 'BND','BRL','BWP','CAD','COP'],
    'operator':['divide', 'multiply', 'divide', 'divide','divide','multiply','divide','divide'],
    }    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

for dfcurrency in df.columns:
    for df1currency in df1['currency']: 
        if(dfcurrency == df1currency):   
            operator = df1[df1['currency'] == df1currency]['operator']

            for j in (operator):
                if(j == 'multiply'):
                    for k in range(0,df.shape[0]):
                        df[df1currency][k] = df[df1currency][k] *1
                elif(j == 'divide'):
                    for l in range(0,df.shape[0]):
                        df[df1currency][l] = round(1/df[df1currency][l],4)
print(df)


     Date   AUD  BWP     CAD     BND     COP
  0  01-01-2019  98.0   30  0.0200  0.9901  0.0500
  1  01-01-2019  98.5   31  0.0192  0.9524  0.0476
  2  01-01-2019  99.0   33  0.0196  0.9709  0.0435
  3  01-01-2019  99.5   32  0.0196  0.9804  0.0476
  4  01-01-2019  97.0   31  0.0192  0.9709  0.0455
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to replace the text "multiply" and "divide" to an operator using [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
import operator as op

operators = { "multiply": op.mul, "divide": op.itruediv }
```

get just the column we want to map these to:

```
new_op = df1.iloc[1:,1]
new_set = new_op.map(ops)
new_set =pd.Series(new_set) 
new_set.index -= 1 #for some reason I had to reset the index
```

and the new set of operators from your list

```
new_set
```

is

```
0         <built-in function mul>
1    <built-in function itruediv>
2    <built-in function itruediv>
3    <built-in function itruediv>
4         <built-in function mul>
5    <built-in function itruediv>
6    <built-in function itruediv>
Name: operator, dtype: object
```

So, to apply the converted text as an operator to your data, here is an example for the 'AUD' column:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
df.loc[i,'AUD'] = new_set[i](1,df.loc[i,'AUD'])
```

Will yield,

```
        Date    AUD     BWP     CAD     BND     COP
0   01-01-2019  98.000000   30  50  1.01    20
1   01-01-2019  0.010152    31  52  1.05    21
2   01-01-2019  0.010101    33  51  1.03    23
3   01-01-2019  0.010050    32  51  1.02    21
4   01-01-2019  97.000000   31  52  1.03    22
```

You should be able to generalize this to all columns or add new lines for each country codes, e.g.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
df.loc[i,'AUD'] = new_set[i](1,df.loc[i,'AUD'])
df.loc[i,'BWP'] = new_set[i](1,df.loc[i,'BWP'])
....
```